# OverlayTrigger Tooltip Not Showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

Created codesandbox to show issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-https-2xjs2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I'm wanting a Tooltip to show whenever I'm hovering over a card. I need to pass in a value from the OverlayTrigger to the Tooltip component. With the following code, nothing is showing when hovering over a card:

Character.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Infott from '../components/Infott'

const Character = ({ character }) => {
  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      trigger='hover'
      placement='bottom'
      overlay={<Infott test={'Test'} />}
    >
      <Card className='my-3 py-3 rounded'>
        <a href={`/character/${character._id}`}>
          <Card.Img src={character.image} />
        </a>
      </Card>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  )
}

export default Character
```

Infott.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Infott = ({ test }) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip id='character-tooltip' placement='bottom'>
      <strong>{test}</strong>
    </Tooltip>
  )
}

export default Infott
```

If I add `className=show` to the Tooltip component, it will show and the test value is passed, but it's no longer placed next to the card but rather the bottom left of the webpage. My guess is the OverlayTrigger and Tooltip are not on the same page.

I can get the Tooltip placement showing and in the correct placement if I change overlay to `overlay={Infott}` and then change my Tooltip component to

```
const Infott = (props) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip id='character-tooltip' placement='bottom' {...props}>
      <strong>{test}</strong>
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

But then I'm not able to pass the test value that I need.

Answer (score 1):

OverlayTrigger seems to use ref to the target Tooltip for some actions as well as some properties that it injects so in order to work properly you must forward a ref from your custom component to the target Tooltip you have wrapped inside.

So the correct solution for having your Tooltip wrapped in a custom component should be something like:

```
const Infott = React.forwardRef(({test, ...props}, ref) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip id='character-tooltip' ref={ref} placement='bottom' {...props}>
      <strong>{test}</strong>
    </Tooltip>
  );
});
```